# Storing multiple avatars

Tags: thumbnails, storage, avatars

I want to make bigger application that stores multiple avatars for each registered user (different sizes of the same image).
Should I store original images and resized avatars in the same directory (small_avatar and big_avatar stored in the same directory) or should I keep different sized images in matching directories (small_avatar goes to small_avatar directory, big_avatar goes to big_avatar directory etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not there will be any difference but if you try to check some of the world`s largest websites you will see that they are keeping all in the same directory just with different prefixes. My guess is that saves some load time but I seriously doubt it is significant for the user or server.